# Firebase: Check for existing before adding

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am adding data with generated ID's but am trying to group "Authors".

I have a script that adds certain people to this every day based on a few formulas. There is no way for me to know who will be added on any given day so I am forced to structure the database by have it generate the keys on submission (push) and then locating the author key and finding other keys with the same value.

The issue I'm having is checking to see if a value is present before adding a new record. One of the key values is "URL". I have tried to write something to check each record for that value, but it seems to repeat and write to the database regardless of what the value is even though I can properly detect the duplicate.

```
function CheckDupes(newUrl, author, title, score, url, certified, date){
  var stories = [];
  var duped = "false";

  var leadsRef = database.ref().child("Authors").once("value").then(function(authorSnapshot)
  {
    authorSnapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        stories.push(child.val());
      });
    for(var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++)
    {
      console.log("Story: " + stories[i].url);
      if(stories[i].url == newUrl)
      {
        console.log("Duplicate - " + stories[i].url);
        duped = "true";
        alert("Story Exists!");
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(duped);
  if(duped == "false")
  {
    firebase.database().ref('Authors/').push({
      author: author,
      title: title,
      score: score,
      url: url,
      certified: certified,
      date: date
    });
    alert("Story has been added!");
  }
```

This is what I currently have. It will find the duplicate but it adds to the database regardless of whether or not it finds one. I've moved the check outside of the foreach loop, but then it doesn't store anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckDupes(newUrl, author, title, score, url, certified, date){
  var stories = [];
  var duped = "false";
  var leadsRef = database.ref().child("Authors").once("value").then(function(authorSnapshot)
  {
    authorSnapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        stories.push(child.val());
        count++;
      });
      for(var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++)
      {
        if(stories[i].url == newUrl)
        {
          duped = "true";
          alert("Story Exists!");
          return;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(duped == "false")
      {
        firebase.database().ref('Authors/').push({
          author: author,
          title: title,
          score: score,
          url: url,
          certified: certified,
          date: date
        });
        alert("Story has been added!");
      }
  });
```

Needed everything within the authorSnapshot function. Silly mistake.